# Selenium, use same drivers in different loops

Tags: selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate a browser operation, with two browsers running in parallel. I can easely start the drivers, but after that I don't seem to be able to access them with the names driver1, driver 2, or the loop I built for the second step.

```
drivers = ['driver1', 'driver2']

#First step: load the drivers

for dr in drivers: 
dr = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='mypathtoseleniumbrowser')

#Second step: perform different operations in loop, in both drivers, without restarting them

for dr in drivers:
        dr.get('https://www.google.com')
```

The AttributeError it produces is:
"'str' object has no attribute 'get'"

So, the drivers don't seem to get defined by the names 'driver1, 'driver2, otherwise I cound access them.
Can anyone help? Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this or use multithreading.

```
drivers_instance = []
for i in range(2):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='mypathtoseleniumbrowser')
    driver_instance.append(driver)
```

Something in multithreading

```
from threading import Thread

def setUp():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='mypathtoseleniumbrowser')
```

Probably in main

```
threads=[]
for i in range(2):
    process = Thread(target=setUp)
    process.start()
    threads.append(process)
for process in threads:
    process.join()
```

Comment: Thanks! First method works fine. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

By `drivers = ['driver1', 'driver2']` you defined list `drivers` containing two strings, not two `WebDriver` objects